# StringBuilder append content to a new line every time

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I am building a validation routine that validates contents and then gives warning (for failures) in form of [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). Say in below code I am checking lower bound for values paramX and paramY.

```
 StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();

        if(paramX<10){
            sb.append("paramX cannot be less than 10 ");
        }

        if(paramY<20){
            sb.append("paramY cannot be less than 20 ");
        }

        System.out.println(sb);
```

It gives output as: **paramX cannot be less than 10  paramY cannot be less than 20**

but i want output such that, each appended String will be printed on new line. Like below.

```
paramX cannot be less than 10 

paramY cannot be less than 20
```

I used following workarounds, but ended up repeating same code again and again(Which i don't want to).

```
sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator")); // Add Explicit line separator each time
sb.append("\n");
sb.append("paramX cannot be less than 10 \n");
```

Is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Can you not just put the \n at at the end of the original append?

Comment: `sb.append("xxxx\n");` - why not this?

Comment: have you tried adding \n to your first append. sb.append("paramX cannot be less than 10 \n");

Comment: @vlcekmi3 , Matt Penna: as posted above, i want to avoid manual padding / formatting.

Comment: then you can extend `SB` and add corresponding method e.g. `appendLine()`

Comment: @vlcekmi3 : as per my knowlwdge StringBuffer is final class. You can't extend it. Please refer to this url http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html

Comment: @DarkKnight actually you can..

Comment: @vlcekmi3 This is just like writing your custom method with own formatting. which i want to avoid. And by the way it's not extending StringBuilder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just thought of sharing the new feature of jdk 8 i used for achieving same result.
Using StringJoiner we can construct a sequence of characters separated by a delimiter.

```
StringJoiner formattedString= new StringJoiner("\n"); 
formattedString.add("XXX");
formattedString.add("YYY");
System.out.println(formattedString);
```

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to do it over and over then write a helper method:

```
public void appendString(StringBuilder builder, String value) {
    builder.append(value + System.lineSeparator());
}
```

Then call:

```
if(paramX<10){
    appendString(sb, "paramX cannot be less than 10 ");
}
```

This way you only have a single place to maintain if you need to change the output format for the errors.

Comment: `System.lineSeparator()`

Comment: This `builder.append(line); builder.append(lineSeparator);` is more efficient then `builder.append(line + lineSeparator);` since the former creates a new String object for every line.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use Apache Commons StrBuilder, which has the functionality that you're looking for.

[StrBuilder.appendLn()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrBuilder.html#appendln(org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrBuilder))

Comment: It's deprecated now. [Its documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrBuilder.html) recommends to use [org.apache.commons.text.StrBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StrBuilder.html) instead.

Comment: Hmmm, you sure? Doesn't appear to be deprecated. Either way, same functionality.

Answer (score 4):

The simple way would be to keep a list of errors rather than concatenating them as you go. That would help to maintain a separation of concerns between the logical errors and their presentation.

See how Spring validation works: you have an Errors object that keeps a list of errors, and a separate message source object that fills in the user-visible messages for the different errors.

Comment: My problem is, i am working with legacy code. And i don't to touch whole setup just for sake of message formatting. Hope you understood my pain.

Comment: @Dark Knight: yes, understood completely.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a PrintStream as it has an println(String string) method which add the new line automatically.

Something like this.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(bos);
ps.println("Line 1");
ps.println("Line 2");
ps.flush();
String message = new String(bos.toByteArray());
System.out.println(message);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to include the newline character(`\n`) at the end of every `.append()` yourself:

```
sb.append("paramX cannot be less than 10 \n");
```

As for repeating you *new-line logic* just wrap it in a method:

```
public void append(StringBuilder sb, Object value) {
    sb.append(value).append(System.getProperty("line.separator")).append('\n');
}
```

And use it like:

```
if(paramX < 10){
    append(sb, "paramX cannot be less than 10");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

simply append directly...

```
        if(paramX<10){
            sb.append("paramX cannot be less than 10 \n ");
        }

        if(paramY<20){
            sb.append("paramY cannot be less than 20 \n ");
        }
```

Comment: Please read above post. I want to avoid manual padding. I would really appreciate if i get certain workaround which does not pad line formatting manually.

Comment: may be create your own function. but can't extend StringBuilder StringBuffer classes. Because it is final classes. so you create your custom function. but i think again you must use "\n" mannually.

Comment: Yes, you have to do this manually, or set up something more complicated with streams.  The joys of java :D

Answer (score -1):

Just use `\n` - it will work everywhere. Also, it looks like you want to conditionally add a line feed if there are *two* messages:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

if (paramX<10) {
    sb.append("paramX cannot be less than 10 ");
}

if (paramY<20) {
    if (!sb.length() > 0) // only add newline if needed
        sb.append('\n');
    sb.append("paramY cannot be less than 20 ");
}
```